# when to use map() function and when to use summarise_at()/mutate_at()

Tags: r, purrr, modelr

Can anyone give a suggestion regarding when to use the `map()` (all map_..()  functions) and when to use `summarise_at()`/`mutate_at()`?

E.g. if we are doing some modification to the column of vectors then we do not need to think `map()` ?
If we have a df / have a column has a list in it then we need to use `map()`?

Does `map()` function always need to be used with `nest()` function?
Anyone could suggest some learning videos regarding this. And also how to put lists in df and modeling multiple lists at the same time then store the model results in another column ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Might be to broad / opinion / asking about tutorials is off topic. That said, I'm interested to see if there are any answers. Btw here is a [purrr tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/index.html) by Jenny Brian

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The biggest difference between {dplyr} and {purrr} is that {dplyr} is designed to work on data.frames only, and {purrr} is designed to work on every kind of lists. Data.frames being lists, you can also use {purrr} for iterating on a data.frame.

```
map_chr(iris, class)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
   "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

`summarise_at` and `map_at` do not exactly behave the same: `summarise_at` just return the summary you're looking for, `map_at` return all the data.frame as a list, with the modification done where you asked it :

```
> library(purrr)
> library(dplyr)
> small_iris <- sample_n(iris, 5)
> map_at(small_iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), mean)
$Sepal.Length
[1] 6.58

$Sepal.Width
[1] 3.2

$Petal.Length
[1] 6.7 1.3 5.7 4.3 4.7

$Petal.Width
[1] 2.0 0.4 2.1 1.3 1.5

$Species
[1] virginica  setosa     virginica  versicolor versicolor
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

> summarise_at(small_iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), mean)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1         6.58         3.2
```

`map_at` always return a list, `mutate_at` always a data.frame :

```
> map_at(small_iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), ~ .x / 10)
$Sepal.Length
[1] 0.77 0.54 0.67 0.64 0.67

$Sepal.Width
[1] 0.28 0.39 0.33 0.29 0.31

$Petal.Length
[1] 6.7 1.3 5.7 4.3 4.7

$Petal.Width
[1] 2.0 0.4 2.1 1.3 1.5

$Species
[1] virginica  setosa     virginica  versicolor versicolor
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica

> mutate_at(small_iris, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), ~ .x / 10)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1         0.77        0.28          6.7         2.0  virginica
2         0.54        0.39          1.3         0.4     setosa
3         0.67        0.33          5.7         2.1  virginica
4         0.64        0.29          4.3         1.3 versicolor
5         0.67        0.31          4.7         1.5 versicolor
```

So to sum up on your first question, if you are thinking about doing operation "column-wise" on a non-nested df and want to have a data.frame as a result, you should go for {dplyr}.

Regarding nested column, you have to combine `group_by()`, `nest()` from {tidyr}, `mutate()` and `map()`. What you're doing here is creating a smaller version of your dataframe that will contain a column which is a list of data.frames. Then, you're going to use `map()` to iterate over the elements inside this new column.

Here is an example with our beloved iris:

```
library(tidyr)

iris_n <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest()
iris_n
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species    data             
  <fct>      <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

Here, the new object is a data.frame with the colum `data` being a list of smaller data.frames, one by Species (the factor we specified in `group_by()`). Then, we can iterate on this column by simply doing :

```
map(iris_n$data, ~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x))
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     2.6390       0.6905  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     3.5397       0.8651  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  Sepal.Width  
     3.9068       0.9015
```

But the idea is to keep everything inside a data.frame, so we can use `mutate` to create a column that will keep this new list of `lm` results:

```
iris_n %>%
  mutate(lm = map(data, ~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    data              lm      
  <fct>      <list>            <list>  
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: lm>
```

So you can run several `mutate()` to get the `r.squared` for e.g:

```
iris_n %>%
  mutate(lm = map(data, ~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)), 
         lm = map(lm, summary), 
         r_squared = map_dbl(lm, "r.squared")) 
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    data              lm               r_squared
  <fct>      <list>            <list>               <dbl>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: summary.lm>     0.551
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: summary.lm>     0.277
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> <S3: summary.lm>     0.209
```

But a more efficient way is to use `compose()` from {purrr} to build a function that will do it once, instead of repeating the `mutate()`.

```
get_rsquared <- compose(as_mapper("r.squared"), summary, lm)

iris_n %>%
  mutate(lm = map_dbl(data, ~ get_rsquared(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    data                 lm
  <fct>      <list>            <dbl>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.551
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.277
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.209
```

If you know you'll always be using `Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width`, you can even prefill `lm()` with `partial()`:

```
pr_lm <- partial(lm, formula = Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width)
get_rsquared <- compose(as_mapper("r.squared"), summary, pr_lm)

iris_n %>%
  mutate(lm = map_dbl(data, get_rsquared))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    data                 lm
  <fct>      <list>            <dbl>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.551
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.277
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> 0.209
```

Regarding the resources, I've written a series of blogpost on {purrr} you can check: https://colinfay.me/tags/#purrr

Answer (score 0):

Colin gives a great self-contained answer. Since you asked for more resources on using multiple models with tibbles, I'd also like to add the Many Models chapter of R 4 Data Science which gives a broad overview of creating, simplifying, and modeling with list-columns. http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html